# positioning images absolute inside a relative

Tags: html, css, css-position

this should be main page where logo(img) is in the centre of page and on the 3 sides ( left/right/bottom )of that will be images used as links - see example img--

https://ibb.co/bAah2v      -> (black square = logo, yellow rhombus= links/images and everything should scaling to browser resolution)

got problem with absolute positioning. images are positioning to whole screen instead of logo which should be parent i think ?(according to w3school-> https://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_position_absolute)

or maybe there is other methods to get good positioning, adjustment and scaling depends on browser resolution?(js/php?)

Thanks for your time,ideas and help

html

```
<body>
<div id="main_logo">
<img class="logo_glowne" src="X.png" alt="Logo" </img>
  <div id="main_menu">
                <a href="t_aktualnosci.html"><img class="taniec" src="Z.jpg" alt="."/></a>
                    <a href="odziez.html"><img class="wear" src="Z.jpg" alt="."/></a>
                    <a href="adres"><img class="adres" src="Z.jpg" alt="." /></a>

   </div>
</div>
</body>
```

css

```
  body{
margin: 0;
padding: 0;

}/*full screen div */
#main_logo {
position:relative;
width:100%;
height:100%;
background-color:black;
}
/* logo center */
img.logo_glowne {
max-width:100%;
height: auto;
display: block;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
position:relative;
}

img.taniec{width:60px;height:60px;position:absolute;bottom:20%;left:50%;}
img.wear {width:60px;height:60px;position:absolute;top:48%;left:80%;max-width:100%;}
img.adres {width:60px;height:60px;position:absolute;top:48%;left:20%;max-width:100%;}
```

Comment: can you please send an image of your problem?

Comment: <img class="logo_glowne" src="X.png" alt="Logo" </img> this is wrong

Comment: <img class="logo_glowne" src="X.png" alt="Logo" > it should be like this

Comment: make some effort and paste in Google, you'll get first (best) result:
https://css-tricks.com/absolute-positioning-inside-relative-positioning/

Comment: the problem is that absolute positioning doesnt work at all

as you can see on this example image ->  https://ibb.co/fKY22v
minions ( which represent link image) follows browser window when i change the resolution they should stay close to the logo 

so basically they are still related to static body not relative logo and i dont know what im doing wrong...

@pkolawa  belive me or not i made some effort and research even among many questions here but i still dont know what's wrong with that code or maybe im just stupid and my eyes have enough of this :D

Answer (score 0):

to have absolute position **INSIDE** relative you need to place absolute element **INSIDE** relative element. You need to place `position: relative` on #main_menu like this:

```
#main_menu{
    position: relative;
}
```